# Find a bijective mapping that shows that [0,1] and [0,1) have the same cardinality

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I need to show that the two sets $[0,1]$ and $[0,1)$ have the same cardinality. I know that in order to show this I must show that there exists $f$ such that $f:[0,1]\to[0,1),$
but I am not sure how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: But $f(1)=1$, which is not in $[0,1)$.

Comment: Well that was a silly oversight. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119851/1-1-correspondence-between-0-1-and-0-1) or [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621313/bijection-between-a-b-and-a-b-intervals). It is very similar to [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1) and you can also have a look at [other posts linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/160738). (I voted to close as a duplicate.)

Comment: Instead of a bijection, would you accept a pair of injections, one in each direction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Define:

\begin{equation} f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{1+n}, & \text{if $x = \frac{1}{n}$ , $n \in \mathbb{N}$ }.\\ x , & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases} \end{equation}

Comment: Sorry, but what is n?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned $n \in \mathbb{N}$ , I hope its clear now.

Comment: This $f$ would not be unique, would it? I imagine there are other bijections, correct?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is not unique.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my edited question... I tried to find an alternative mapping. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkWatson There are an infinite number of bijections.

Comment: I just want to make sure my $f$ was indeed bijective. I know it is surjective but want to make sure it is injective as well. I cannot think of a case that shows otherwise.

Comment: @Mark  Consider $A=\{x: x= \frac{1}{n}, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, then it will be enough to show that f is injective on $A$ which is easy.

Answer (score 5):

These sorts of things often boil down to using the fact that there is a bijection between the nonnegative integers and the positive integers, allowing you to shift everything over by one to make room for an extra point (e.g. the Hilbert hotel paradox); you just need to find a suitable copy of $\mathbb{N}$ in the problem.

In fact, we can completely characterize the bijections:

**Lemma:** every bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1)$ can be uniquely expressed as:

- An injection $g : \mathbb{N} \to [0,1)$
- A bijection $h : [0,1) \setminus g(\mathbb{N}) \to [0,1) \setminus g(\mathbb{N})$

and conversely, given such data, there there is a corresponding bijection

$$ f : [0,1] \to [0,1) : x \mapsto
\begin{cases}
g(0) & x = 1 
\\ g(g^{-1}(x) + 1) & x \in g(\mathbb{N})
\\ h(x) & x \in [0,1) \setminus g(\mathbb{N})\end{cases} $$

Comment: This is really the same spirit as my answer...

Comment: @Ian: Well, every answer is ultimately going to boil down to "write $[0,1) \cong A \cup \mathbb{N}" so there is a limit on how much variation is available. I find my presentation somewhat more transparent, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered posting.

Comment: @Ian Indeed. But I do like the intuition presented in the first paragraph. Especially for the level of the question, when these concepts can seem bizzare.  A variety of presentations of the same notions is a good idea: different people will find different presentations more in tune with their way of thinking.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance I like it better now that the first paragraph has been edited in.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $A \subset [0,1]$ is countably infinite and $1 \in A$. Then $[0,1] \setminus A=[0,1) \setminus A$. So the identity function, call it $f$, is a bijection from $[0,1] \setminus A$ to $[0,1) \setminus A$. Can you define a bijection, call it $g$, from $A$ to $[0,1) \cap A$? Once you have done that,

$$h(x)=\begin{cases} g(x) & x \in A \\
f(x) & x \not \in A \end{cases}$$

is a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1)$. A hint for constructing $g$: consider enumerating $A$ as a sequence $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ with $x_1=1$.

Comment: I am curious about what you think about the top answer?

Comment: @MarkWatson It's equivalent to this one, it just gives you $A$ and the bijection from $A$ to $[0,1) \cap A$.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my edited question... I tried to find an alternative mapping. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkWatson I think you send both $0$ and $1$ to $0$.

Comment: But $m > n$ so $f > 0$

Comment: @MarkWatson Wait, are you mapping all the positive rationals in a different fashion, or just $n/m$? Also, what is $f(1)$?

Comment: I am mapping the positive rationals $0 < \frac{n}{m} < 1$ and everything else from $[0,1]$.

Comment: @MarkWatson Then where does $1$ go? It seems that you are sending $1$ to itself, which you cannot do.